# Policy-based authorization - Auth0 Authentication - Always Returns Forbidden 403

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, auth0

I am using Auth0 to get some Authentication and Authorization working in my Backend API server. Auth0 uses a system of Roles + Permissions, which are compatible with policy concept described here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1

On, the user side, I have no issues, collecting the tokens. When I study the token, I notice that the necessary scopes are coming through.

```
{
  "iss": "https://randomquoteexperimental.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "removedonpurpose",
  "aud": [
    "https://thechalakas.com",
    "https://randomquoteexperimental.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1601906519,
  "exp": 1601992919,
  "azp": "removedonpurpose",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [
    "read:penquotes"
  ]
}
```

Further, on the same API server, endpoints without scope, both without token, and with token, return just fine. So, the API server is good, and is reading scope-free authorization just fine.

On my API server, I have the following. this is my ConfigureServices.

```
    // Register the scope authorization handler
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        //TODO1 - similar to above , migrate this also to appsettings.json
        options.AddPolicy("capquotes", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:capquotes", "https://randomquoteexperimental.us.auth0.com/")));
        options.AddPolicy("penquotes", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:penquotes", "https://randomquoteexperimental.us.auth0.com/")));
    });
```

And, here is a simple endpoint, that I am trying to access.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("PenScope1")]
[Authorize(Policy = "penquotes")]
public ActionResult<GeneralAPIResponse> PenScope1()
{
    var tempItemViewModel = new GeneralAPIResponse();
    var tempString1 = "You have the PEN Scope as per the rules"; 
    tempItemViewModel.ListOfResponses.Add(tempString1);
    return tempItemViewModel;
}
```

I have followed the official guide, available here - https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization#configure-the-sample-project

Since, the tokens are coming in with the right permissions, and they are issued by the API server that is configured on the Auth0 system, I am assuming, everything is fine as far as Auth0 is concerned.

So, I believe, I am making a mistake on my .NET Core project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer. Ultimately, in fact, lies with the Token, and what is coming.

Although, the scopes, I need are coming here,

```
  "permissions": [
    "read:penquotes"
  ]
```

.NET Core is not looking under permissions for the necessary scopes. It was looking here.

```
"scope": "openid profile email",
```

and since, the neccessary scopes dont exist there, the authorization was denied. Eventually, I updated my React client app to ask for the neccessary scopes.

Now, look at the correct token,

```
{
  //other token things
  "scope": "openid profile email read:penquotes"
}
```

Now, the authorization is going ahead without any problems. Looks like my .NET Core configuration was fine, but I was making a mistake when requesting for the token.